# Rational sections of projective bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why does a projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E) \to X$, with $E$ a vector bundle on $X$, always have rational sections? How do you construct them?

Comment: Vector bundles are locally trivial, so on a dense open set you can choose a line sub-bundle. Projectivising then gives a rational section.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti thank you!

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti this looks like an answer to me. Would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 1):

Vector bundles are locally trivial, so on a dense open set you can choose a line sub-bundle. Projectivising then gives a rational section.